# AutoComplete dissapears when importing typescript module namespace in vs 2013

Tags: autocomplete, module, visual-studio-2013, typescript, intellisense

Imagine:

[image]

[image]

Ok, so in vs 2013 (update 2) this works fine, no red squiggles or anything. But in the "OtherClass", when writing "im.", i get no auto-complete with suggestions of "MyInterface", as I would expect.

[image]

If i write something that does not exist in the namespace, the red squiggles appear. So some kind of intellisense exist.

[image]

If I however skip the "import" part and write the whole namespace: "foo.bar.a." I get auto-complete all the way and suggestion of MyInterface at the end.

[image]

I would like to use the import syntax to get shorter lines, but if I won't get auto-complete, suggestions, it's not worth it.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Getting the auto-complete while using import i mean.
Thanks!

The interface is auto generated by web essentials from a c# model, if that would help.

**Update**

Ok, so I found a setting under Tools -> Text Editor -> Typescript -> General
called "Auto list members". It was unchecked so I checked it and it does come up with the suggestion, but, it looks weird.
[image]
[image]

If you look closely you see that the suggestion is sort of on top of other the suggestions. Even in the second case which worked fine before. It does look like the screen shot Steve Fenton took, with the small white down arrow under the blue thing(an arrow that does not show for me when writing entire namespace in the First case), so I guess he might have this option checked.  But it seems for me it does not work as well.

**Update 2**

Ok so the thief was resharper. Sorry I forgot to mention i used it.
I fixed it by changing to use vs 2013 Auto list members for typescript and shut it off for resharper like so: http://www.cloud-developer.eu/blog/2013/12/03/solved-intellisense-working-typescript-resharper-installed-using-visual-studio-2012/

But i checked "Visual Studio", instead of "Limited ReSharper Intellisense"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as I stated it seems it was ReSharper intellisense vs Visual Studio 2013 intellisense.

The link under my Update 2 was a fine solution for me before, when I had Resharper 8.1 installed.

But it seems they have improved it and in 8.2 the original issue is fixed. So I have now unchecked the "auto list members" in vs2013 options and only use resharper.

Comment: yes, I will, but it seems I have to wait 2 days before accepting my own answer

Answer (score 0):

It *works for me*™, which suggests one of the following...

It could be a problem with the language service. This normally resolves when you close and re-open the file or when you restart Visual Studio.

If this isn't the case, it may be a bug in Visual Studio - something is making it mess up. You will almost certainly be asked to uninstall/reinstall before anyone will look at your bug, so do that if you still have a problem and see if it fixes it.

If neither of these help, it will be time to raise a bug for Visual Studio :(

Here is my screen shot of the working code:

[image: Working code in Visual Studio 2013]

Comment: I found the problem, I had resharper intellisense, which seems worse than vs 2013 i guess. I updated the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem using VS2013 and Resharper 8.2 but this was due to a error on my side in the path to the module I required. So I guess there is a bug that misses the error from my side...